# How to get bold, italic styles within a div

Tags: javascript, html

Am working on a text editor where the content can be in the form of following

```
<div>some text <strong>bold text</strong> more <em>italic</em></div>
```

Now on some user click, I have to remove the bold and italic styling from the div.

How can I remove the strong and em tags from a div?

Thanks

Kapil

Comment: on click of the div or the text that is strong/bold ?

Comment: On the click of a button in a toolbar

Comment: Ah - why not use a truly tested one like [tinymce](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/)

Answer (score 4):

**HTML**

```
<div id="foo">
 <div>some text <strong>bold text</strong> more <em>italic</em></div> 
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var t = document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML;
t = t.replace('<strong>', '');
t = t.replace('</strong>', '');
t = t.replace('<em>', '');
t = t.replace('</em>', '');
document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML = t;
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if you want jQuery, but it handles things like this nicely:

```
// To remove styles from clicked element.

$('#editor *').click(function () {
  $(this).replaceWith($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: he asked about javascript not jquery

Comment: Oh well. I'll keep it here to convince the author that vanilla JS gets hard to work with when doing element manipulations...

Comment: This will remove all formatting. This may be what you want. This may not be what you want. In the latter case, turn `$(this)` into `$('strong,em', this)`

Answer (score 3):

```
var element = document.getElementById('whatever');

element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.replace(/<(strong|em)>(.*?)<\/\1>/g, '$1');
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/ruaq9/).

Keep in mind any events attached to any children of this `div` will be lost.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use regular expressions or some other kind of text replacement for this. The DOM is a tree. Treat it as such and don't be scared of it. It's by far the safest and least brutal way to handle this kind of thing.

```
function removeElements(container) {
    var elements = container.getElementsByTagName("*");

    // Make an array of the strongs and ems
    var strongsAndEms = [];
    for (var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; ++i) {
        if (/^(strong|em)$/i.test(elements[i].tagName)) {
            strongsAndEms.push(elements[i]);
        }
    }

    // Remove the strongs and ems
    for (var j = 0, el, child; el = strongsAndEms[j++]; ) {
        while ( (child = el.firstChild) ) {
            el.parentNode.insertBefore(child, el);
        }
        el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
    }
}

var div = document.getElementById("foo");
removeElements(div);
```

Comment: I'd +1 if you didn't *ugh* my answer... :)

Comment: @alex: Heh. It was a little late, and I didn't apply my usual self-censors. Sorry.